# When did *wooden* 'nails' (pegs) for clay roof tiles go out of fashion?

Tags: 19th-century, england, construction

Judging by Google searches, *wooden* 'nails' for fixing roof tiles are definitely a thing of the past. However almost all the searches I have attempted (in an area I don't know my way around) have only turned up offers to sell metal or plastic 'nails'. The closest I came to anything useful were:

[ROOFING](https://content.historicengland.org.uk/images-books/publications/roofing-conservation/roofing-marketing-spread.pdf/) from English Heritage, and

[How to Tell the Age of a Barn](https://superior-hardwoods.com/how-tell-age-barn/) from Superior Hardwoods at least mentions nails but they are metal, and the context is USA, similarly [History & Photo Examples of Nails](https://inspectapedia.com/interiors/Nails_Hardware_Age.php) from InspectAPedia.

Wikipedia has [Treenail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treenail) but those are used differently.

At least a drawing of one at [PEG TILES IN SOUTH-EAST ENGLAND](https://www.molevalley.gov.uk/media/pdf/b/0/Peg_Tile_Leaflet_OPT.pdf) from the Society For The Protection Of Ancient Buildings (bottom left on page 3).

So I have searched, but unsuccessfully, for some indication of **when [wooden](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wooden) pegs ceased to be in common use** (replaced by metal ones) for 'fixing' clay tiles (hand-made) for roofs. In particular for southern England (specifically, West Sussex).

Can anyone indicate a date?

<sub>I'd guess about the middle of the 19th Century.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[The Heritage Directory](http://www.theheritagedirectory.co.uk/uploads/articles/Peg%20Tiles.pdf) reports that peg tiles were introduced in the 12th century and "were the universal form of plain tile till the 19th century". Specifically, "[b]y 1850, nib tiles were being used and were common by the 1880's."

The [City and Countrey Purchaser, and Builder's Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=g7FbAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PA269&ots=X37bt07ooF&dq=pan%2C%20crooked%2C%20or%20Flemish%20tiles%2C&hl=es&pg=PA271#v=onepage&q&f=false) of 1703 describes curved "Flemish" tiles that "have no holes for Pins", so curved and lapping tiles also appeared during the period when pegs were used to fix plain tiles.